# Unexpected lubridate interval behavior when filtering dataframe via dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I am creating a `lubridate` interval vector using a dataset similar to that which is available in the following chunk:

```
dat <- readr::read_rds(url("https://github.com/mienkoja/stack_stash/blob/master/dat.rds?raw=true"))

dat_mod <- dplyr::mutate(dat, interval = lubridate::interval(lubridate::ymd(start_combo)
                                                             ,lubridate::ymd(stop_combo)))
```

If I try to filter the object via `dplyr`, however, I get an unexpected interval returned:

```
dplyr::filter(dat_mod, id == 7000)

## A tibble: 1 x 4
#     id start_combo stop_combo                       interval
#  <int>       <dbl>      <dbl>                 <S4: Interval>
#1  7000    20170802   20170816 2016-10-11 UTC--2016-10-25 UTC
```

Indeed, every interval (viewed via `dplyr::filter`) appears to be the same length as the expected interval, but all anchored (incorrectly) to 2016-10-11 UTC.

I suspect this is a `dplyr::filter` bug as I can search by bracket notation and get the expected result.

```
dat_mod[dat_mod$id == 7000, ]

## A tibble: 1 x 4
#     id start_combo stop_combo                       interval
#  <int>       <dbl>      <dbl>                 <S4: Interval>
#1  7000    20170802   20170816 2017-08-02 UTC--2017-08-16 UTC
```

Before I report the bug, however,  I figured I'd reach out here to see if I am missing something and this behavior is by design.

---

**Question: Is it possible to use `dplyr::filter` and retrieve actual `lubridate` intervals (as retrieved via "bracket notation")?**

---

**Update: Since nobody has jumped on this, I am going to assume this is a bug for the time being. See the following issue posted on GitHub: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3206**

**I'll update in both places once I get a fix (via GitHub) or a solution (via SO).**

Comment: Seems possibly related to [this open issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2568)

Comment: It's a known limitation of the tidyverse that has to do with C-level dispatch for coercion, subsetting and aggregation. We have long term plans to deal with this.

Comment: @lionel, as I commented in the GH issue, would you guys entertain a warning message for S4 columns in a dataframe? It seems like something that could be checked within the R function before jumping to the "C-level" method.